# Question about a survey, set theory

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

My question says,

**Marco surveyed his 34 classmates and found that:**

**- 12 had a cat**

**- 13 had a dog**

**- 14 had fish**

**- 5 had a cat and a dog**

**- 4 had a cat and fish**

**- 3 had a dog and fish**

**- 2 had all three**

**How many students had no pets?**

I'm not sure how to solve this question as I just started learning about set theory and logic. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$|A\cup B\cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$

and

$$|A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c| = |S|-|A\cup B\cup C|$$

Letting $A$ be the set of students with a cat, $B$ the set of students with a dog, $C$ the set of students with a fish, and $S$ the set of students overall, the problem statement gives us all of the relevant values above.